# string .IndexOf with startIndex

Tags: c#, .net

when you use a startIndex in a IndoexOf method if not match is found does it return -1 or your startIndex? I ran this in my code and want to make sure what I got is right.

Comment: Well, what happens when you try it?

Comment: Seems like nobody has a compiler these days

Comment: @SwDevMan81: Crowd sourcing unit tests. hmmmm. it could be the next hot thing.

Comment: one time i got the startIndex and another time i got -1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will return -1 just like in the other overload of IndexOf.
A quick way to find answers to things like this is a great little app called [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/), which allows you to write and run little snippets of code on the fly.

Answer (score 5):

It returns -1 if no match is found. [It clearly says so in the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s.aspx).